# How to find $ \int\sqrt{\sin x\cos x}\,dx $

Tags: integration

I have been working on days to find the integral of the following question:
$$
\int\sqrt{\sin x\cos x}\,dx
$$
Any anyone please help in finding the solution of that question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I have been working on days to find the integral of the following question*

Even if you were to have kept on working on it for *years*, you still would not have been able to reach any conclusion, since it cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for more information. However, we have $$\int_0^\tfrac\pi4\sqrt{\sin x\cos x}~dx~=~\int_\tfrac\pi4^\tfrac\pi2\sqrt{\sin x\cos x}~dx~=~\frac12\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sqrt{\sin x\cos x}~dx~=~\dfrac{\pi\sqrt\pi}{\Gamma^2\bigg(\dfrac14\bigg)}$$ See [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals), and their relation to the [beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram gives the following result :

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt%28sin%28x%29cos%28x%29%29

As you can see, there is no "nice" antiderivate to $\sqrt{sin(x)cos(x)}$

Comment: Can also be expressed as an elliptic integral.